# Removing all values from a dictionary in an optimal way

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've a dictionary like :

```
z = {'d': '2018', 'uc': '609', 'bc': 'HSBC', 'ab': 'FICCL', .... }
```

It has 57 key-value pairs. I want to keep the keys but remove the values and make them vacant string like "". I have tried the following code :

```
for k,v in z.items():
    z[k] = ""
```

I get the desired output like :

```
z = {'d': '', 'uc': '', 'bc': '', 'ab': '', .... }
```

I was wondering whether this is the easiest way to remove all values at once in a dictionary. Is there any other way? Is there any built-in function to do this? Is there any one-liner without any loop?

Comment: That's a fine way if you need to update the dictionary *in place*. Otherwise, create a new dictionary from the keys.

Comment: You could use `z.update(dict.fromkeys(z, ""))` perhaps.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I read [this post](https://cito.github.io/blog/never-iterate-a-changing-dict/) telling you to *never iterate a changing dictionary*. Hence, the approach you used is not guaranteed to work

Comment: @KenHBS: you can't add or delete keys. Updating values while iterating is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to update the dictionary *in place*, you do have to iterate over the keys, so yours is a good and readable method. It is also faster than alternative methods of updating the your dictionary, or even creating a new dictionary with the same keys!

You can drop the `items()` call, you are not interested in the values. Just loop directly over the dictionary to get keys:

```
for k in z:
    z[k] = ""
```

The alternative is to use [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) to create a new, empty dictionary. To update an existing dict *in-place* (so other references to the same dictionary see the changes) you can call `z.update()` passing in the new dictionary:

```
# set all values to an empty string, in place
z.update(dict.fromkeys(z, ""))
```

The disadvantage would be that you may need to include a comment to explain what the line is supposed to achieve. It is also *slower*, because a new object is being created just to update an existing object. In addition, you want to *careful* using `dict.fromkeys()` as the second argument is a single value that is reused for all keys. This matters if you were to use a mutable value like a list. If all you need is a *new* dictionary, you would dispanse with `z.update()` and just assign the `dict.fromkeys()` result directly to `z`.

Assuming that you need to have *in-place* updates, a quick comparison of performance differences:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> testdict = {i: i for i in range(10 ** 6)}
>>> def explicit_loop(d):
...     d = d.copy()
...     for k in d:
...         d[k] = ""
...
>>> def dict_fromkeys(d):
...     d = d.copy()
...     d.update(dict.fromkeys(d, ""))
...
>>> def base_copy(d):
...     d = d.copy()
...
>>> count, total = Timer("f(t)", "from __main__ import base_copy as f, testdict as t").autorange()
>>> base_copy_time = total / count
>>> for f in (explicit_loop, dict_fromkeys):
...     count, total = Timer("f(t)", f"from __main__ import {f.__name__} as f, testdict as t").autorange()
...     print(f"{f.__name__:>15}: {((total / count) - base_copy_time) * 1000:.2f} milliseconds")
...
  explicit_loop: 43.15 milliseconds
  dict_fromkeys: 68.66 milliseconds
```

Note that to facilitate an accurate test, the input dictionary needs to be copied each time, which is why there is a `base_copy` test to adjust timings.

You can see that the explicit loop over `z` is clearly the winner. But even if you do *not* need to update the dictionary in-place, using `dict.fromkeys()` is slower than updating `z` in-place!

An in-place update doesn't have to dynamically resize a dictionary to fit an arbitrary number of keys, and no new object needs to be created:

```
>>> def dict_fromkeys_no_update(d):
...     d = d.copy()  # to keep comparisons fair, copy only needed for the loop case
...     d = dict.fromkeys(d, "")
...
>>> for f in (explicit_loop, dict_fromkeys_no_update):
...     count, total = Timer("f(t)", f"from __main__ import {f.__name__} as f, testdict as t").autorange()
...     print(f"{f.__name__:>25}: {((total / count) - base_copy_time) * 1000:.2f} milliseconds")
...
            explicit_loop: 41.27 milliseconds
  dict_fromkeys_no_update: 54.78 milliseconds
```

So, whether or not you need a new dictionary or an in-place update, just a simple Python loop over the existing dictionary keys is the undisputed winner here.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout method `fromkeys`
So that'll be `z = z.fromkeys(z, '')`
Hope that helps

Comment: Again, this assumes that creating a *new* dictionary is fine, instead of an in-place update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `.items()`, so your code can be simplified:

```
for k in z:
    z[k] = ""
```

I don't think that there's a one-liner that does the same thing and is equally efficient / readable. Using a loop is totally fine here IMO (unless there's a specific reason why you'd need a single function call).

Comment: I am not an expert, but I read [this post](https://cito.github.io/blog/never-iterate-a-changing-dict/) telling us to *never iterate a changing dictionary*. Hence, the approach you used is not guaranteed to work

Comment: You're iterating over the keys `k` here and only modifying the values, which is totally fine. Deleting / adding items while iterating a dict is indeed dangerous.

Comment: @KenHBS: iteration and setting values is just fine. There would be an issue only if you add or remove keys, as that alters the iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

```
z = dict.fromkeys(z.keys(), "")
```

Comment: This assumes that creating a new dictionary is fine. What if the OP needs to have it updated **in place**?

Comment: You also don't need to call `.keys()` here, `z` is already an iterable of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromkeys` to create a dictionary from a list of keys, and specify what the 'empty' values should be.

```
empty_dict = dict.fromkeys(original_dict.keys(), '')
```

Comment: This assumes that creating a new dictionary is fine. What if the OP needs to have it updated **in place**?

Comment: You also don't need to call `.keys()` here, as `original_dict` is already an iterable producing the keys.

Answer (score 0):

summarising and timing various posted answers, they all seem to come out roughly equal in runtime.

I start by creating a relatively large `dict`:

```
src = {str(i):i for i in range(1_000_000)}
```

using `dict.fromkeys`:

```
dict.fromkeys(src.keys(), '')
```

takes 183 ms ± 11.7 ms.  note that Mohammad's `z.fromkeys(z…` is doing the same.

the `dict` comprehension:

```
{k:'' for k in src.keys()}
```

takes the same at 183 ms ± 5.11 ms.  note that `iter(src)` is [just shorthand](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for `iter(src.keys())` and I generally prefer to be explicit

while an inplace mutate:

```
for k in src.keys():
    src[k] = ''
```

is slightly faster at 162 ms ± 6.15 ms.

Comment: How did you time these? I come to the same conclusions, but you need to make sure you create a new full dictionary for each test iteration to ensure a fair test run. In the end, it doesn't matter if the values are all already set to an empty string, but in theory the lack of memory churn could make a difference.

Comment: I used `timeit` with `setup` doing `x = src.copy()` and the actual code using `x` instead of `src`.  this will indeed churn memory slightly awkwardly, but thought it wouldn't matter much